I am trying to solve a system of differential equations when one derivative vanishes
NDSolve[{m*g1'[m] == 1/(16*Pi^2)*41/6*g1[m]^3, m*g2'[m] == 1/(16*Pi^2)*(-19/6)*g2[m]^3, 


 m*g3'[m] == 1/(16*Pi^2)*(-7)*g3[m]^3,
m*gla'[m] ==  1/(16*Pi^2)*(24*gla[m]^2  - 9*gla[m]*(g2[m]^2 + 1/3*g1[m]^2  + 9/8*g3[m]^4), 


g1[Mt] == 0.36, g2[Mt] == 0.66,g3[Mt] == 1.2, gla[Mt] == 0.1}, {g1, g2, g3, gla}, {m, Mt, MU}]

I am trying to solve the system of above equations and, specifically i want to find the energy (m), in which the derivative gla'[m]==0, where Mt=92, MU=10^16

g1,g2,g3 seem to be completely independent of gla.  So try DSolve[{m*g1'[m]==1/(16*Pi^2)*41/6*g1[m]^3,g1[Mt]==36/100},g1,m] and do the same for g2 and g3. Then substitute all those results into DSolve or NDSolve for gla. Please report back whether it worked

I would like to tell you Bill, that the system is solved, but to be more specific, the main problem i want to adress is to find the m, where gla ' [m]==0, in this system! Thank you in advance! Ioannis

The gla ODE is missing a closing parenthesis.  Please correct.

Mt=92; g1[m_]:=36*Pi/Sqrt[10000*Pi^2+1107*Log[92]-1107*Log[m]]; g2[m_]:=132*Pi/Sqrt[40000*Pi^2-6897*Log[92]+6897*Log[m]]; g3[m_]:=6*Sqrt[2]*Pi/Sqrt[50*Pi^2-63*Log[92]+63*Log[m]]; s=NDSolve[{m*gla'[m]==1/(16*Pi^2)*(24*gla[m]^2-9*gla[m]*(g2[m]^2+1/3*g1[m]^2+9/8*g3[m]^4)), gla[Mt] == 1/10},gla,{m,1,1000}]; Plot[Evaluate[gla[m]/.s],{m,1,1000},PlotRange->All] does not look promising for finding gla[m]==0 unless I've made a mistake.

@Bill, I agree.  gla'[m] approaches zero only asymptotically at infinite m.

Ok Bill, thanks for your comments. They have been very helpful! I'm wondering if we could use the second part of the equation, meaning  FindRoot [1/ (16Pi^2)(24*gla[m]^2...........)==0, {m,Mt,,MU}], to find gla'[m]==0?

How to you expect to use FindRoot on the unknown function gla[m]? If you can find gla[m] then just differentiate it, set it equal to zero and solve for m. It does not look like DSolve is going to find gla[m] for you. It appears more feasible to show that gla'[m] decreases for increasing m and decreases more slowly for increasing m.  If you can defend that then gla'[m]==0 when m==Infinity and you are done. Maybe. But I'm not ready to claim that.

Putting gla1L [m_] : = gla[m] / . s[[1,1]], we can solve the second part of the above equation FindRoot[24* gla1L[m]^2-9* gla1L[m]*..............]==0, {m,1,1000} ] it seems to work! The only problem is that it gives m=2914.61, which lies out of the range of the interpolating function...! Thanks, anyway Bill!

So change the 1000 to 10^4 and repeat this. I suspect again the solution will lie out of range. So change the 10^4 to 10^5 and repeat this. I suspect again the solution will lie out of range. So change the 10^5 to 10^6 and repeat this. I suspect you will run into accuracy and precision problems if you keep this up. But it you can learn enough to get good enough solutions then I suspect this will happen for all finite ranges.

You're absolutely right! I have tried it and it still gives solutions out of the range of the interpolating function...! But , i don't know, i'm just wondering, if there is another, more accurate way of handling this kind of problem? Maybe, another command?
